# html width case

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div class="div1">
     <div class="div2">Title:</div>
     <div class="div3">Test</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.div1{
   width:500px;
}
.div2{
    float: left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.div3{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Example
[image]

I want the underline fill all the div1 except div2("Name:") which is blank at present.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the image of what you want to achieve, if not please attach that (may be some example) too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can right like this

```
<div class="div1">
     <div class="div2">Title:</div>
     <div class="div3">Test</div>
</div>



.div1{
   width:500px;
}
.div2{
    float: left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.div3{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

check the example http://jsbin.com/apudil/4/edit#preview